# How can I set up my skills for use underwater?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I noticed that when I go underwater, my healing and utility skills all change to the default setup I had when I first started playing the game, before I made any customizations.

This leads me to believe that you can specify separate skill sets for normal combat and underwater combat. It only makes sense, since you have a different weapon in each case.

How can I pick which skills I will have available underwater?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change your Utility skills for your underwater skill set, simply dive underwater, click the arrow, and select the skill you want to have in that slot.

[image]

The skills with the red Xs on them can't be used underwater, but the others can. In my case, I chose Sharpening Stone. Once I get back on land, however, it will automatically switch back to Signet of the Hunt.

[image]